# Get value on appended element with button submit

Tags: php, jquery, html

When I click the submit on button, the appended elements are not submitted. I already tried to change `append()` to `appendTo()` and `html()`. Please help.

```
$('select[name="bidang"]').on('change', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var id_bidang = $(this).val();

      // AJAX request
      $.ajax({
          url: '<?php echo base_url()?>form_jurnal/getSubBidang',
          method: 'GET',
          data: {
            id_bidang: id_bidang
          },
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(response) {

            $('select[id="sub_bidang"]').empty();
            $.each(response, function(key, value) {
                $('select[id="sub_bidang"]')
                  .append('<option value="' + value.id_subbidang + ' 
                    selected ">'+ value.nama_subbidang +'</option>');
                  });

            }
          });
      });
```

---

```
<label>Sub Bidang   :</label>
<select id="sub_bidang" name="sub_bidang">
    <option>--Pilih Sub Bidang--</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you share your response data here from console.log(response);?

Comment: is your 'change' event is firing correctly?

Comment: i have tried with on.submit function and it's works, but I have two submit button in one form

If I use on.submit function, the specific field can't selected and it's post all fields

Comment: check your console

Comment: in console return error that some value null, because 'sub_bidang' not return a value